# Asp.net 4 connection string issue

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am having the following error

```
 public int  GetRegisteredUsersCount()
    {

        string myScalarQuery = "select count(*) from aspnet_Users where isActivated = 0";
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["uniteCms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString());

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myScalarQuery, myConnection);
        myCommand.Connection.Open();
        int count = (int) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        myConnection.Close();

        return count;
    }
```

but yet i have the connection string in my webconfig connections string section

```
 <add
name="uniteCms"
connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial 
Catalog=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37;User ID=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37_admin;Password="
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

[image]

Comment: change initial catalog to database

Comment: connectionstrings.com will help you.

Comment: @KenTucker please provide and answer ill mark u up Girggi its its stackoverflows policy not to provide links outside of asp.net documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data source instance are you using?
If you are using sqlexpress then you should put Data source=myserver\sqlexpress. For any instance it should be like Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have line breaks in your connection string which also is what the error implies (ie `Initial\r\nCatalog`).

Make sure to not put any line breaks within the attribute values.

```
<add
  name="uniteCms"
  connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37;User ID=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37_admin;Password="
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If you really want to break it down you can try adding it after the delimiters in the connection string but I'm not sure it will be allowed there either.

This might work, might fail with a crash or might fail without saying anything and giving you an exception later about being unauthorized (because only the first line was used).

```
<add
  name="uniteCms"
  connectionString="Data Source=myserver;
                    Initial Catalog=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37;
                    User ID=DB_9DF962_davidbuckleyni37_admin;
                    Password="
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```